# Not getting value correct value from sqlite table OR not inserting it properly

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have two sqlite tables in a specific database. I want to add the same data to both tables but on the second table I want to also store the ID of that entry in the first table.

What I do is add the entry ('Name', 'Description') to the first table then query to get the 'ID2' value then add the entry and the ID2 number into my second table after (Put ID2 in as ID3). I always rawquery to get my last entry's 'ID2' column value.

I have this working in the sense that it doesnt crash and does add a value to my second table BUT its isnt adding the value but instead some sort of reference which I do not understand so cant look up.

I would like a solution to get the the last 'ID2' value of my first table and insert it into my second table in 'ID3' column ALSO I would like an explanation of why what I have below is wrong.

Please reference my Java code below and screenshots of my two databases (the second showing the reference code not the value I want)

Thank you so much.

```
public boolean insetTheme(String name2,String Description){
    SQLiteDatabase Mydb =this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues newThingAdd = new ContentValues();
    newThingAdd.put(COL2_ALLTHEMES,name2);
    newThingAdd.put(COL3_ALLTHEMES,Description);
    long result = Mydb.insertOrThrow(TABLE_ALLTHEMES,null,newThingAdd);

    Cursor res = Mydb.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_ALLTHEMES + " where 'ID2'" ,null);
    //res.moveToLast();
    if (res != null) {
        res.move(-1);
    }

    ContentValues newThingAdd123 = new ContentValues();
    newThingAdd123.put(COL2_CURRENTTHEMES,name2);
    newThingAdd123.put(COL3_CURRENTTHEMES,Description);
    newThingAdd123.put("ID3",res.toString());
    long result2 = Mydb.insertOrThrow(TABLE_CURRENTTHEMES,null,newThingAdd123);

    if ((result==-1)&(result2==-1))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

[First Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOxDC.jpg)

[Second Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYonD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

res is a `Cursor` so calling `toString()` on it won't give you what you want.

You need to use `res.getString(0)` or similar with the specific method based on what type the value is (String, int, boolean etc) and the number being the column number, for example, if the value you want is the third column that would be returned in the query, use `res.getString(2)` to get the value.

If I made a query like this:

`Cursor cursor = Mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_1");`

and table_1 had 3 columns:

`id, name, date`

if I wanted the name, I would use

`String name = cursor.getString(1);`

Hopefully this is what you were after.

Comment: Brett thanks for this!

In the past I was using res.getstring(0) but it was giving an error for what I though was because I have only 1 value in res not 3 as the above - this was because I had used the "where 'ID2'" addition to my rawquery. 

The solution above works if I know how many columns I have but I am likely going to add columns in future on the fly using "alter table" query so being able to distinguish my values by the name of the column is preferable. Perhaps I went wrong with the "where" in my rawquery and the res.getstring(0) will still work. 

Any advice?

Thanks again!

Comment: Sqlite doesn't support alter table. In order to add a column you have to duplicate the table, recreate it with the new column and then copy the data over. Regardless, you'll likely have to keep track of the order of the columns at least as you can probably get the number of columns dynamically then just offset from that. Sqlite is a bit limited unfortunately.

Comment: Brett I can confirm that i have successfully used 'alter table' in my code elsewhere. 

I think I will change my approach to work as described above. 

Thank you.